# What are words like most, greatest, best etc. categorised as?

Tags: category

Basically the words Donald Trump likes to use. Not thinking of quantifiers or nouns. Something that emphasises words? Some category for describing extremities?

Answer (score 1):

Superlatives.

> of, relating to, or constituting the degree of grammatical comparison that denotes an extreme or unsurpassed level or extent - [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/superlative)

Comment: Thank u! Ah yes exactly what i was looking for.